# Using python to Extract data from lines in file

Tags: python

I have a file with many lines of data much data like:

> chr1:4797973-4836816   57.7862

I want to create a new file with lines that look like:

> chr1    4797973    4836816    57.7862

chr# varies from line to line. # = 1-19, X, Y
Sorry if this is so basic... 
J

Comment: What have you tried? Pleas post your attempt, or ask a specific question about what you haven't figured out.

Answer (score 4):

Yes its too basic. You should have tried to refer the documentation and come up with a solution. Here is one that would serve your purpose

```
>>> with open("in1.txt") as fin, open("out1.txt","w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace(":"," ").replace("-"," "))
```

Things you need to understand:

1. Python [with](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/with.html) statement.
2. [open](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) statement to open a file
3. How to  read and write a file
4. Using [string.replace](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html)

Please note you can also use translate instead of replace, but that would eat up two characters from your string.

Comment: My apologies. Thank you for taking to time to answer!